# How to successfully deploy to bot service through app service local git deploy?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-bot-service

I've developed a simple chatbot based on the sample python bot (24. ms graph auth bot) and was deploying it through the CLI - it worked like a charm. However, the deployment was taking ages (at least 7 minutes per deployment) and I've tried to use other deployment methods because I have to prototype authorization on the Azure side (I'm not allowed to install ngrok...). I've had a few problems with git deployment to Azure App Service but finally it seemed like it started to work, the problem is - once I thought it'll work, instead of errors I'm receiving empty log.

Last line in the botname.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/date_code_docker.log:

```
2020-03-03 07:41:41.123 INFO  - Container botname_0_letters for site botname initialized successfully and is ready to serve requests.
```

It usually indicated that everything works correctly. However, there is nothing in the botname.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/date_code_default_docker.log - as if there was nothing running. Bot service through webchat receives Internal Server Error. When I was debugging it there was data in the default_docker.log with errors about gunicorn app:app, but since I've solved it and container started to be initialized successfully - the default_docker.log doesn't get any new lines, it looks like the app wasn't working.

Any clue what might be a reason of it? Why is the log empty and bot doesn't work? Deployment from .zip file through Azure CLI worked correctly, it has AppID and AppPassword set up (and it worked through the .zip deployment), is there anything I should take care of when deploying from local git which is done automatically when deploying .zip through CLI?

Comment: hi @zak Are you still having this issue? The log you are mentioning are empty; are these the logs that show up in the app service Deployment Center?